# How delete all comments of Source code in my c# solution with roslyn?

Tags: c#, roslyn

I want to delete all comment in my source code in my C# solution with Roslyn.
but How should i do that ?

```
public void DeleteComment()
{
        var code = File.ReadAllText("code.cs");
        SyntaxTree tree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(code);
        ///Delete Comments ?

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just some extensions to @SLaks' answer. You need to extend `CSharpSyntaxRewriter` and override the `VisitTrivia` method. And here you'll need to check the `Kind` of the trivia. Depending on your needs, you should filter for single and multiline comments:

```
trivia.IsKind(SyntaxKind.SingleLineCommentTrivia) || trivia.IsKind(SyntaxKind.MultiLineCommentTrivia)
```

And return `default(SyntaxTrivia)` to remove them from the tree.